# cannot rectify the error

Tags: visual-c++

I have this piece of code:

```
static char szTop[] = "iMsg             wParam              lParam";
static char szUnd[] = "____             ______              ______";
static char szFormat[] = "%-16s%04X-%04X        %04X-%04X";
static char szBuffer[50];
static HWND hwndButton[NUM];
```

And it gives me error :

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ']' before ';'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ']'
```

Another code is:

```
for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    hwndButton[i] = CreateWindow ( "button", button[i].text, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | button[i].style, cxChar, cyChar * (1+2*i), 20*cxChar, 7*cyChar/4, hwnd, (HMENU) i, ((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam )->hInstance, NULL );
return 0;
```

And this gives me error:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'i'
error C2059: syntax error : ';'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'hwndButton
```

I have defined the required things previously as:

```
static char szTop[] = "iMsg     wParam              lParam";
static char szUnd[] = "____         ______      ______";
static char szFormat[] = "%-16s%04X-%04X        %04X-%04X";
static char szBuffer[50];
static HWND hwndButton[NUM];
static RECT rect;
static int cxChar,cyChar;
HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
int i;
TEXTMETRIC tm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that first one, this can be caused by not having a definition in place for a type or macro, most likely `HWND` or `NUM`.

For the second one, it's complaining about the use of `hwndButton` before defining it, simply because of the first error - that variable was never defined because the statement that tried to define it had that earlier error error.

First, verify that you have included the correct headers. I *think* it's in `windef.h` but is usually included by the `windows.h` header file.

Second, ensure that `NUM` is actually defined somewhere.

I think it's probably the `NUM` one simply because one of the errors comes from the `for` loop statement, where `windows.h` stuff is not used but `NUM` is.

Comment: I have included windows.h, i tried including the windef.h but with no luck its still giving the errors

Comment: @rohit, there's one other possibility why that `hwndButton` definition may fail (`NUM` not existing) - I've added that to the answer.

Comment: i have defined NUM as: #define NUM ( sizeof button / sizeof button[0] );

Comment: this is my struct for defininng the buttons--                  struct { long style; char *text; } button[] = { BS_PUSHBUTTON, "PUSHBUTTON", BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, "DEFPUSHBUTTON", BS_CHECKBOX, "CHECKBOX", BS_AUTOCHECKBOX, "AUTOCHECKBOX", BS_RADIOBUTTON, "RADIOBUTTON", BS_3STATE, "3STATE", BS_AUTO3STATE, "AUTO3STATE", BS_GROUPBOX, "GROUPBOX", BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, "AUTORADIO", BS_OWNERDRAW, "OWNERDRAW" };

Comment: @rohit, I'm not sure what else I can tell you. If there is indeed an error on the `for` statement, it can _only_ be `i` or `NUM`, and a non-existent variable usually gives a clearer message. My advice would be to recheck your definition of `NUM`, specifically _where_ it is done (header file, position in C++ file and so on) and confirm it exists when you're trying to use it. If necessary, add the lines `#ifndef NUM`, `#error URK`, `#endif` to your code before the `hwndButton` declaration.

Comment: thnx for helping out .. I figured out the solution ,,,I dont know why but it was not taking NUM definition ,so I just replaced NUM with whatever I had defined in the macro and its working perfectly..!!!